# draw function CustomPaint and PictureRecorder work in different sizes

Tags: flutter

I want to watermark an image, the draw function is different in Custom Paint, it gives different dimensions in PictureRecorder. As the size of the photo increases, the draw gets smaller. How do I fix it?

```
CustomPaint(
                          painter: painter.ImagePainter(
                              image: snapshot.data,
                              text: text,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: fontSize,
                                color:
                                    Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, fontOpacity),
                              ),
                              logo: _logo),
                          willChange: true,
                        )
```

To png:

```
    ui.PictureRecorder recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    Canvas canvas = Canvas(recorder);
    ui.Image image = await _retrieveImage();

    Watermark.draw(
        canvas,
        image,
        text,
        TextStyle(
            fontSize: fontSize,
            color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, fontOpacity)),
        Size(image.width.roundToDouble(), image.height.roundToDouble()),
        _logo);

    ui.Image pic =
        await recorder.endRecording().toImage(image.width, image.height);
    ByteData data = await pic.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
```

Comment: what does `CustomPaint` have to do with `PictureRecorder`? `PictureRecorder` does not need it: all you need is `ui.Image` object you want to draw

Comment: The user sees what he has changed with the CustomPaint. Then it saves and downloads with PictureRecorder.

Comment: This is exactly my problem https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53519

Comment: I can save the image but after saving the Watermark size is different.

Comment: no, it is the same: `water.png: PNG image data, 640 x 360, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced` and `images/clouds.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 1x1, segment length 16, progressive, precision 8, 640x360, components 3` - as you can see "watermarked" image and original image  sizes are the same

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed with this function:

```
Matrix4 sizeToRect(Size src, Rect dst,
    {BoxFit fit = BoxFit.contain, Alignment alignment = Alignment.center}) {
  FittedSizes fs = applyBoxFit(fit, src, dst.size);
  double scaleX = fs.destination.width / fs.source.width;
  double scaleY = fs.destination.height / fs.source.height;
  Size fittedSrc = Size(src.width * scaleX, src.height * scaleY);
  Rect out = alignment.inscribe(fittedSrc, dst);

  return Matrix4.identity()
    ..translate(out.left, out.top)
    ..scale(scaleX, scaleY);
}
```

Also i deleted canvas.translate function

Thanks to @pslink